# Fail to send image after setting custom HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have built a REST API with a Spring. Most of the controllers return JSON responses. I also have one controller for fetching images (they can't be referred statically because I have to authorize access to them).

This is my controller's method for images:

```
@RequestMapping("/image/{id}")
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> get(@PathVariable ObjectId id) throws IOException {
    InputStream image = imageRepository.findOne(id);
    if (image == null) {
        throw new Http404Exception("Image not found.");
    }
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(image);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    headers.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(imageBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This method worked until I needed to configure Jackson to return dates in specific format. After I added the following configuration as [suggested in the docs](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#user-content-without-spring-boot), images are not returned properly.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebappConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
    }
}
```

The image response is as follows (browser tells that it returned the data but can't display the image).

[image: browser response]

I inspected the responses with Fiddler, here are the results. They are completely different for the same image.

Not-working image:

[image]

Working image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add a HttpConverter that will handle images appropriately before Jackson converter can get to them. Fortunately, Spring provides  `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` Final configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebappConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
}
```

}

Comment: When you use `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.configureMessageConverters` none of the default converters is registered. So you may run into the same situation again.

Comment: What are the defaults converters then?